# Aligning parameters between parenthesis in "aligned" algorithmicx (correctly)

Tags: algorithmicx

It's hard to use words, this is what it is supposed to look like

[image]

It's close, but my solution is super hacky.  If I were in a verbatim environment, I'd be trying to get something like

```
current <- positions( i ,  j )
south   <- positions( i , j+1)
east    <- positions(i+1,  j )
```

where ideally, the `i` is aligned with the `+` from the bottom row etc.  Only I want a mathy `i` because they're quite pretty ;)  Here's the ridiculous concoction I crafted:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for \textcolor
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

% https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=1scm
\newlength{\maxwidth}
\newcommand{\algalign}[2]% #1 = text to left, #2 = text to right
{\makebox[\maxwidth][l]{#1{}}{} #2}

% these make me so sad!
\newcommand{\iZero}{\textcolor{white}{+}\textcolor{black}{i}\textcolor{white}{0}}
\newcommand{\jZero}{\textcolor{white}{+}\textcolor{black}{j}\textcolor{white}{0}}
\newcommand{\iOne}{i\textcolor{black}{+1}}
\newcommand{\jOne}{j\textcolor{black}{+1}}
\newcommand{\iMinOne}{i\textcolor{black}{-1}}
\newcommand{\jMinOne}{j\textcolor{black}{-1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{An algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \settowidth{\maxwidth}{current}
        \State \algalign{current}{$\gets$ positions$(\iZero, \jZero)$}
        \State \algalign{south}{$\gets$ positions$(\iZero, \jOne)$}
        \State \algalign{east}{$\gets$ positions$(\iOne, \jZero)$}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I tried to do something similar to the `algalign` for the parenthetical statements, but I don't think you can `\makebox` inside of a `\makebox`.  Currently, my ridiculous macros are so sensitive it isn't even funny.  You have to `\textcolor{black}{+1}` otherwise TeX will add otherwise desireable spacing between the `j` the `+` and the `1`.  Plus, heaven forbid, if somebody actually copies it they'd get something like `positions(+i0, +j0)`!

Any suggestions on how to get these all lined up nice and savvy?  I feel like there could be a way, but maybe this falls more in the domain of "this is stupid, don't do this".  I just feel like without the spacing it's harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the similar-width content in boxes using [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State \eqmakebox[cse][l]{current} $\gets$ positions$(\eqmakebox[pos-i]{$  i  $}, \eqmakebox[pos-j]{$  j  $})$
    \State \eqmakebox[cse][l]{south}   $\gets$ positions$(\eqmakebox[pos-i]{$  i  $}, \eqmakebox[pos-j]{$j + 1$})$
    \State \eqmakebox[cse][l]{east}    $\gets$ positions$(\eqmakebox[pos-i]{$i + 1$}, \eqmakebox[pos-j]{$  j  $})$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Since `eqparbox` uses a `\label`-`\ref`-like system to establish the correct width, you'll have to compile twice the first time around.

`\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` sets all `<stuff>` with the same `<tag>` in a text mode box of similar width with an appropriate `<align>`ment.

Comment: WOHOOOO!  Thanks, this is my new favorite package -- I can use eqparbox to solve a **lot** of other problems I have right now :)  Why did you do `[1]` after `\begin{algorithmic}`?

Comment: @sjm324: That provide the stepping of line numbers, if you wish to add that to your pseudocode. `[2]` would only mark every second line.

Comment: Ugh. Duh.  Trial and error would have sufficed.  Anyway, thanks again for showing me this package, I've gone back through and fixed all of my algorithm listings and they look MUCH better now!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

with help of `tabular` environment followed `\State`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\newlength{\maxwidth}
\newcommand{\algalign}[2]% #1 = text to left, #2 = text to right
{\makebox[\maxwidth][l]{#1{}}{} #2}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{An algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}
%        \settowidth{\maxwidth}{current}
        \State {\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
        \begin{tabular}{lcl @{}c@{,\,}c@{}l}
        current & $\gets$ & positions( & $i$   & $j$   & )\\
        south   & $\gets$ & positions( & $i$   & $j+1$ & )\\
        east    & $\gets$ & positions( & $i+1$ & $j$   & )
        \end{tabular}}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: An equally valid answer, but this limits me to alignment  in one "state".  This definitely answers the question, but `eqparbox` allows me to align things in different "states" as well.  (sorry for the accidental accept, my browser auto-refreshed and I hadn't even read this answer yet!)